# Unable to connect an app to IIS server running postgresql

Tags: postgresql, iis, pdo

I realise this will be a very vague post. We have a new server running Windows server. It turns out it was not setup fully.

It was missing the IIS webserver.

I have set up IIS, installed PHP7 using Web Platform Installer, and tested the connection through a psql PDO connection. We have an android app which communicates to the database via php, it uses a PDO connection. The app works when we point it to our old server 192.168.1.102 but it gives an error when we direct it to the new server 192.168.1.100

I've added these extensions to the php.ini file:

```
extension=php_pgsql.dll

extension=php_pdo_pgsql.dll
```

Here is the contents of the db connection which was setup by someone else a few years ago:

```
<?php

class PgDB {

    private $dbConnection;


    function __construct() {
        $this->dbConnection = new PDO('pgsql:dbname=' . PG_DB .';host=' . PG_HOST . ';user=' . PG_USERNAME . ';password=' . PG_PASSWORD);

        $this->dbConnection->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);
        $this->dbConnection->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    }

    function getDB() {
        return $this->dbConnection;

    }
}
```

And here are the connection parameters (with sensitive information replaced by `<>`, note both files lack the `?>` ending for some reason, I assume poor practice to exclude this?

```
<?php
/**
 * Created by PhpStorm.
 * User: msenol
 * Date: 02.04.2015
 * Time: 11:57
 */

// PG info
define("PG_HOST", "192.168.1.100");
define("PG_PORT", "5432");
define("PG_DB", "<database name>");
define("PG_USERNAME", "<usrname>");
define("PG_PASSWORD", "<pw>");

// SQL Fields
define("TYPE", "reading_location");
define("HUE", "hue");
define("LIGHTNESS_VALUE", "lightness_value");
define("CHROMA", "chroma");
define("DESCRIPTION", "description");

// Image Upload Path
define("BASE_IMAGE_PATH", "e:/gygaia/images/");

define("TEST_MODE", false);
```

I used the standard script to connect and was successful.

```
<?php


$dsn = "pgsql:host=$host;port=$port;dbname=$db;user=$user;password=$pw";

try{
 // create a PostgreSQL database connection
 $conn = new PDO($dsn);

 // display a message if connected to the PostgreSQL successfully
 if($conn){
 echo "Connected to the <strong>$db</strong> database successfully!";
 }
}catch (PDOException $e){
 // report error message
 echo $e->getMessage();
}
$conn = null;
?>
```

We are all at a loss, and we need the system up and running since we are on fieldwork.

Comment: ok, so my next goal is to test the pdo class based connection to see if the php is connecting to the database, not sure how to test a class based pdo connection.

Comment: _"note both files lack the `?>`"_ - yes, it is normal practice to omit this for classes and other files that do not emit HTML.

Comment: _[the new server] gives an error_ - what is the error?

Comment: It is just a general error coming from somewhere within the Java app, I've decompiled it, but that does not help much.

Comment: I changed the standard script from `localhost` to `192.168.1.100` and it gives the error at the end of this comment. So it looks like I need a pg_hba file, I have vague memories of this ca. 10 years ago! So I need to allow access from `192.168.1.*`

`SQLSTATE[08006] [7] FATAL: no pg_hba.conf entry for host "192.168.1.100", user "<username>", database "<dbname>", SSL off`

Comment: it was the `pg_hba.conf` file, I changed the local address to `samenet` and it now all works. So tomorrow I get to migrate the whole database to our new system and we can start the archaeological field season with a fully working system on Monday!

Comment: Good work! Are you able to summarise the solution in an answer below, in case it is useful for future readers?